# How to generate the Typescript files from proto files?

Tags: typescript, protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-node

I'm attempting to generate some Typescript files for a React project that would utilize gRPC through proto files.

I ran a script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

IN_DIR="./protos"
OUT_DIR="./dist"

# Generate the types
yarn proto-loader-gen-types \
    --grpcLib=@grpc/grpc-js \
    --outDir=${OUT_DIR}/types/ \
    ${IN_DIR}/*.proto
```

This somehow only generates the types and interfaces without the actual services. Apologizes if I am using the wrong terms, I am new to doing gRPCs.

Is there another script that I need to run to generate the meat of the files that I need to start working with gRPC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If any input file has service definitions, the output will have the corresponding service interface definitions. No additional options are needed to make that happen. Keep in mind that the output directory structure reflects the packages declared in the `.proto` files, so this proto file:

```
syntax = "proto3";

import "google/protobuf/empty.proto";

package foo.bar;

service TestService {
  rpc TestMethod (google.protobuf.Empty) returns (google.protobuf.Empty);
}
```

will result in a file containing the service interfaces in `${outDir}/foo/bar/TestService.ts`.

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm late but here is my solution. Save to compile_proto.sh and make sure it has execute permission with `chmod +x compile_proto.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
# Initialize variables for input and output directories
PROTO_ROOT_DIR=""
OUTPUT_DIR=""

# Parse command-line arguments for input and output directories
while getopts "i:o:" opt; do
  case $opt in
    i) PROTO_ROOT_DIR="$OPTARG" ;;
    o) OUTPUT_DIR="$OPTARG" ;;
    *) echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG" >&2
       exit 1
       ;;
  esac
done

# Validate that directories have been provided
if [ -z "$PROTO_ROOT_DIR" ] || [ -z "$OUTPUT_DIR" ]; then
  echo "Usage: $0 -i <input_directory> -o <output_directory>"
  exit 1
fi

# Check if the output directory exists, if not create it
if [ ! -d "$OUTPUT_DIR" ]; then
  echo "Output directory $OUTPUT_DIR does not exist. Creating..."
  mkdir -p "$OUTPUT_DIR"
fi


# Function to compile proto files
compile_proto_files() {
  for PROTO_FILE in "$1"/*.proto; do
    if [ -f "$PROTO_FILE" ]; then
      echo "Compiling $PROTO_FILE..."
      protoc --plugin=protoc-gen-ts=./node_modules/.bin/protoc-gen-ts --ts_out=grpc_js:$OUTPUT_DIR -I $PROTO_ROOT_DIR $PROTO_FILE
    fi
  done

  for SUB_DIR in "$1"/*/; do
    if [ -d "$SUB_DIR" ]; then
      compile_proto_files "$SUB_DIR"
    fi
  done
}

# Start the script
echo "Starting proto compilation..."
compile_proto_files "$PROTO_ROOT_DIR"
echo "Proto compilation complete."
```

Usage:

`./compile_proto.sh -i ./path/to/proto/files -o ./path/to/generated/ts`